# Restart in service manager calls start before stopping all threads

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows service with multiple background worker threads.
In `OnStart` I am calling each threads `Start()` and in `OnStop` I am calling `CancelAsync()` with proper `thread.Sleep`.

I am facing an issue in restart. When user clicks restart in service manager I am getting below error:

> "System.IO.IOException: All pipe instances are busy."

The reason is below code:

```
this.serverStream =
        new NamedPipeServerStream(SERVER_PIPE_NAME, PipeDirection.In, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message ,
          PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
```

I can have only one instance of NamedPipeServerStream. During restart all the threads are not stopped hence getting 2 instance.
Please guide me how I can avoid starting the service before all the threads are stopped.